# Meaning of the word "twang" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> When someone tells you how busy they are, and you feel that **twang** that you should be doing more, think twice.

It is from [*Psychology Today*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-initiative/201708/why-people-dont-just-display-social-status-money). I am aware of what the word *twang* means, but not sure what the author means by it in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that the author was thinking vaguely of "twinge"

> a mental or emotional pang:
>   a twinge of guilt; twinges of sorrow.

or "pang"

> a sudden sharp feeling

and combined the two.

It also has the connection that a twang is a resonant vibration which occurs after an object has been struck or plucked (for strings). The image evoked is of an internal vibration caused by the realization that one should be doing something.

Comment: +1 for **twinge** + **pang**

Answer (score 1):

The author is comparing the moral or social imperative - perhaps a twinge of conscience - to be active and useful with the tingling, resonance of a musical instrument or bow (and arrow) string.

It's that feeling that one gets in one's chest from a sudden emotion or realisation.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twang
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/twang